Spring application does not respond after successful start
I stumbled upon the same strange error, that is described here: related question
I upgraded my Spring boot application from version "2.7.18" to "3.3.0".
I updated dependencies versions in my "pom.xml" file, changed "javax.xxx" imports to "jakarta.xxx", fixed "SecurityConfig" to get rid of depricated API and made some minor changes according to migration guide to successfully compile and start my app.
This are my start logs:
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:55.667 [background-preinit] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.1.Final
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:55.705 [restartedMain] INFO  xx.xx.xx.Application - Starting Application using Java 17.0.11 with PID 25244 (C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\xxx\xxx-api\target\classes started by user in C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\xxx)
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:55.706 [restartedMain] INFO  xx.xx.xx.Application - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:55.739 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.d.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor - Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:55.739 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.d.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor - For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:55.780 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.c.i.s.PropertySourceProcessor - Properties location [file:${catalina.base}/webapps/application.properties] not resolvable: Could not resolve placeholder 'catalina.base' in value "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/application.properties"
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:56.298 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:56.371 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 66 ms. Found 25 JPA repository interfaces.
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.163 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.170 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.171 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.171 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.24]
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.217 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.218 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1478 ms
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.331 [restartedMain] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.465 [restartedMain] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1643feab
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.465 [restartedMain] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:57.561 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.database - Set default schema name to public
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.133 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Reading from public.databasechangelog
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.210 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.ui - Database is up to date, no changesets to execute
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.212 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Reading from public.databasechangelog
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.242 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.util - UPDATE SUMMARY
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.243 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.util - Run:                          0
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.243 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.util - Previously run:             181
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.243 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.util - Filtered out:                 0
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.243 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.util - -------------------------------
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.243 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.util - Total change sets:          181
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.243 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.util - Update summary generated
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.260 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.lockservice - Successfully released change log lock
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.261 [restartedMain] INFO  liquibase.command - Command execution complete
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.330 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.383 [restartedMain] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.417 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.c.i.RegionFactoryInitiator - HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.477 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.b.internal.EnversServiceImpl - Envers integration enabled? : true
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:58.689 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo - No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.087 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity1
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.088 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity2
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.090 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity3
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.090 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity4
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.090 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity5
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.091 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity6
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.091 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity7
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.091 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity8
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.092 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity9
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.093 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity10
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.093 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity11
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.094 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity12
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.094 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity13
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.094 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity14
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.094 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity15
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.095 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity16
STDOUT: 05.07.2024 13:20:59.095 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator - Adding properties for entity: xx.xx.xx.domain.Entity17

However after that application is not reachable through HTTP, as well as Cron jobs are not executed. For some time (around 20 minutes) application continues running and slowly consume more and more RAM until it takes all available and then crashes with following error:
Exception in thread "RMI Scheduler(0)" Exception in thread "HikariPool-1 housekeeper" Exception in thread "Catalina-utility-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Catalina-utility-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 13:33:28.356 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 13:33:28.412 [restartedMain] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 13:33:28.415 [restartedMain] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 13:33:28.410 [Catalina-utility-3] ERROR o.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase - Exception processing background thread
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.threadStart(ContainerBase.java:1097)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessorMonitor.run(ContainerBase.java:1141)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 13:33:28.420 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 13:33:28.434 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 13:33:28.454 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at xx.xx.xx.Application.main(Application.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

When I try to build project with maven clean install command, I get following error:
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 12:47:57.430 [main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 12:47:57.430 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-12 - Shutdown initiated...
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 12:47:57.431 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-12 - Shutdown completed.
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 12:47:57.433 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger -

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
STDOUT: [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] 05.07.2024 12:47:57.441 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space

My "pom.xml" file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>xx.xx.xx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xx-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>xx-api</name>
    <description>xx</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <lombok.version>1.18.32</lombok.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <lombokMapstructBinding.version>0.2.0</lombokMapstructBinding.version>
        <hypersistenceUtils.version>3.7.6</hypersistenceUtils.version>

        <googleMaps.version>2.2.0</googleMaps.version>
        <firebaseAdmin.version>9.3.0</firebaseAdmin.version>
        <freemarker.version>2.3.32</freemarker.version>
        <flyingSaucerPdf.version>9.7.2</flyingSaucerPdf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
            <version>${googleMaps.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63</artifactId>
            <version>${hypersistenceUtils.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>${firebaseAdmin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>${flyingSaucerPdf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombokMapstructBinding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

And my "application.properies" file:
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix=audit_
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix=

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

I am concerned, that application has enough heap size and the problem is in something else. Before upgrading to the new Spring version java heap space error was not a thing. Also, increasing available heap space makes not difference.
Downgrading to any Spring boot "3.x" versions did not solve the problem.
Do you have any idea, what can cause this strange behaviour?

This question is similar to: How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@aled I edited the question and explained in the end, how It is different

The information you provided is not enough for reproduction. We don't have your application to test, and it would too much for in [so] question to ask to troubleshoot an entire application. The only way to troubleshoot out of heap space issues is by using a memory profiler. That is mentioned in the article I linked. With that analysis you might be able to make a more specific question.
